# Django кнопка login вместо авторизационной формы

Tags: html, django, form, auth

хочу сделай форму для ввода логина, но выводится только кнопка Log in

Вот пример кода:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <hr>

    {% if form.errors %}
      <p> {{ form.errors.error }} </p>
    {% endif %}


    <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
      {{ form }}
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log in</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

То, что выводится на сайт
[image: Первая картинка это то, что выводится на сайт]

То, что я хотел бы сделать
[image: Вторая картинка это то, что я хотел бы сделать]

Заранее, всем спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, нужно было во вьюхах создать класс, который наследует авторизацию (для тех, кто тоже сталкнётся с этим)

Comment: Не подскажите что такое `вьюха`?

Comment: Когда вы создаёте приложение в джанго, то в нём есть файл views.py, в котором вы прописываете, что должно случаться с запросами

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение.